# How can I test Wordpress 4.1 for stability?

Tags: load-testing, agile-testing, test-strategy, security-testing, testability

How could I test (suggest me the test techniques, or what to test) if the latest version of `Wordpress (4.1)` is stable for building a company presentation website?

This is more like a kind of assignment, not something real, that I have to conduct.

my initial thoughts:

the platform is already released, so I would suggest making `domain testing`, `testing for boundaries` and testing for `high loads` on the system.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Could you give a bit more background here? We're not all that keen to do someone's homework for them, so if you could tell us what the context of this request is, what you've come up with so far with more detail than in your question, and why you need help with it, you'll probably get a better response.

Comment: the requirement is to "investigate if wordpress 4.1 is stable enough for a company website". and i already gave you what I came up with: i think that I should test the boundaries (which is included in Domain Testing).

Comment: Who gave you the requirement? What boundaries have you identified? Is the requirement for a self-hosted or the Wordpress hosting service? Why do you need to provide possible tests when you say you don't have to actually do the testing? What kind of tests are you considering domain testing and what kind are you not considering domain testing?

Comment: my teacher :)
and i have to consider both - selfhosted and wordpress hosted site.
and i have to do the testing, i think i missexplained something earlier.
i think that testing for crashes or looking for bugs is unnecessary, sincer the version is already released. so i don't know what kind of tests could i conduct...

Comment: your requirement looks half / not enough.

Comment: So you're asking us to do your homework for you. That's not going to be popular here. If you want good feedback, you're going to need to edit your question to state that  your teacher has asked for this, and to give the answer that you plan to give your teacher and ask if there's anything we think could be improved.